# Can the game client be copied from one location to another without reinstall?

Tags: guild-wars-2

When I originally downloaded the game, I installed it to my RAID array. Now I've noticed I get a fair amount of time on loading screens, with task manager showing large quantities of disc reads during this time, so I'm thinking about moving it onto my SSD to improve the performance of the game when loading between areas.

I have noticed that within the game installation folder there are no utilities, simply the game executable and a handful of data files. Are there any 'repair' command line parameters that can be passed at launch to update whatever entries the game has in the registry etc? Is this even required in this instance?

Can the game client be copied from one location to another without reinstall, or will I need to reinstall/re-download the game?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can copy the .exe and the .dat anywhere, so long as you don't rename them and you keep them next to each other. You won't have to re-download everything.

Everything other than the executable and .dat file should be optional.